# Is there a way to tell Room about custom sqlite functions?

Tags: android, android-room, spatialite

I've implemented `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory` to open a spatialite database (sqlite with spatial functions). However when my queries use spatialite functions such as `ST_AREA`, Room complains that no such function exists. Is there a way to tell room about these custom functions or configure it to skip function checking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling custom SQLite functions in Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043431/calling-custom-sqlite-functions-in-room)

Answer (score 0):

Room can't verify queries with custom functions, please annotate your method with @SkipQueryVerification.

Room verifies your Dao queries using sqlite-jdbc which uses a vanilla prebuilt SQLite native library which doesn't have your custom functions and thus causes the verifier to fail. However, with the @SkipQueryVerification you can make Room skip verifying that query allowing you to still use Room but losing the ability to verify the query at runtime.