# Calling custom SQLite functions in Room

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

I include a custom build of sqlite in my app. I have several custom functions in that library, and I would like to call them from @Query in my Room DAOs. However I get an error that Room couldn't find those functions. Is there a way to tell Room that they exist WITHOUT using a @RawQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Google:

> Room can't verify queries with custom functions, please annotate your method with **@SkipQueryVerification**.
>
> Room verifies your Dao queries using sqlite-jdbc which uses a vanilla prebuilt SQLite native library which doesn't have your custom functions and thus causes the verifier to fail. However, with the @SkipQueryVerification you can make Room skip verifying that query allowing you to still use Room but losing the ability to verify the query at runtime.